# How can I define certain posts only if a variable equals a certain number?

Tags: php

I'm trying to define certain form posts only if the variable `$num = 2` but it doesn't work.

```
if ($num = 2); {
$quant1 = $_POST['Quantity1'];
$item1 = $_POST['Item1'];
$cond1 = $_POST['Condition1'];
    }
```

I get undefined errors when `$num != 0`

Comment: Did you realize you have a semi-colon after your if statement ? `if ($num = 2); { ` That shouldn't be there. : )

Comment: Thanks but that seems to not change anything

Comment: You're also assigning `$num` to be 2 whenever that code executes. I think you wanted to use `if( $num == 2 )` http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning `2` to the variable `$num`, try this instead:

```
if ($num == 2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon (;) after `if($num = 2)` condition. 
and also you are assigning 2 to variable $num.
Use

```
if($num == 2) {
//code here
}
```

instead

```
if($num = 2); {
//code here
}
```

Mind semicolon and remove that and use equality operator instead assignment operator.